# Tyring to stop Thread and stop ffmpeg in background

Tags: java

Hi Im trying to stop a Thread and stop the FFmpeg from continuing in the bachground. So when a user clicks the cancel button it stops the Thread and stop FFmpeg I will show my class MashRocks first , The button calls the method so i guess thats all i should show.

```
package my.mashformcnts;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


/**
 *
 * @author brett
 */
public class MashRocks {

    public static Thread startThread(MashFormCnts mashFormCnts) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i", "C:\\Users\\brett\\Documents\\Telegraph_Road.mp4", "C:\\Users\\brett\\Documents\\out.mp4");
        final Process p = pb.start();
        // create a new thread to get progress from ffmpeg command , override  
        // it's run method, and start it!  
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(p.getErrorStream());
                // Find duration  
                Pattern durPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Duration: )[^,]*");
                String dur = sc.findWithinHorizon(durPattern, 0);
                if (dur == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse duration.");
                }
                String[] hms = dur.split(":");
                double totalSecs = Integer.parseInt(hms[0]) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(hms[1]) * 60 + Double.parseDouble(hms[2]);
                System.out.println("Total duration: " + totalSecs + " seconds.");
                // Find time as long as possible.  
                Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=time=)[\\d:.]*");
                String match;
                String[] matchSplit;
                //MashForm pgbar = new MashForm();
                while (null != (match = sc.findWithinHorizon(timePattern, 0))) {
                    matchSplit = match.split(":");
                    double progress = (Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[0]) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[1]) * 60 + Double.parseDouble(matchSplit[2])) / totalSecs;
                    int prog = (int) (progress * 100);
                    mashFormCunts.setbar(prog);
                }
            }
        };
       t.start();
       return t;
    }
   //This works but is it correct??
   public synchronized static Thread stop(Thread t){
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM ffmpeg.exe");  
        t = null;
      //t.interrupt();
          //im not sure what else to do?


   }
}
```

Also in my form this the code im using to get the Thread and send it to the method

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.print(t);
        MashRocks.stop(t);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that there is a better way. You should store the Process value somewhere and use Process.destroyForcibly() to terminate it. Based on the code you posted, you may want to subclass Thread so you have a place to store the Process that you can get back to easily.

You will also need to store a reference to your custom Thread object when you start it. If there can be only one at a time, you can use a singleton to store the single instance. If there can be multiple, you'll want to create a list or registry of active threads.

Comment: Hi Ian Lovejoy Your suggestion makes sense, except I'm lost as how to do it. May I ask for some advice

Comment: Hey Brett, sure. Let's say you only want to allow one of these to run at a time. When you start your custom Thread (say the class is MyThread), you store the Process inside it. Then you store the reference to the MyThread in a static variable so you can get back to it later. When you want to destroy the process, get the MyThread from the static variable, then get the Process from the MyThread. Killing the process will terminate its output so the thread will stop running on its own (as you've already found). If you want to allow multiple, just use a static List<MyThread> instead. Good luck!

Comment: I guess I should add that if you have another place to store the Process that will stay alive between when you start it and when you want to kill it, that is probably a better choice than static. For example if you have a progress window up, you could store it in that object, or if you have a singleton application object of some sort, you could store it there.